# Detect when reCaptcha does not load

Tags: captcha, recaptcha

What is the best way to detect if a reCaptcha v2 does not load?  I would like to alert users when they need to use the captcha to continue, but it was unable to load.

Comment: You can specify an onload callback function, see https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#explicit_render – that would be “the other way around”, but probably more reliable than trying to check the opposite.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can pass a callback function when you make the request for the captcha

Add this to the url:

```
?onload=myfunction
```

for example:

```
 <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=loadedCallback&render=explicit"
        async defer>
    </script>
```

Js:

```
function loadedCallback(){
//Recaptcha its loaded
}
```